# How do I write a number range that includes all decimals of the last number?

Tags: numbers, lists

I am trying to write out a number range that would include all decimals within the last integer listed. The number range will be used as a label on a web form, so it should be as concise as possible.

For example, if I wanted to list out something that included all numbers between 1 and 99.99999, what would be the best way to write this?

Currently, I have "1 - < 100 meters" which works, but is a little difficult to parse. I am wondering if there is a standardized way to write this.

Comment: This is where different registers are so useful.  Really, one should specify the domain, but 1 ≤ x < 100 would show the semi-inclusive range. The units symbol complicates, but not as much as the 99·99999 as opposed to 99·99 or 99·999999999999999.

Comment: What do you mean by "all decimals within the last integer listed"? Your example only lists one integer (1). The other number is 99.99999, which is not an integer; does it exclude anything above 99.99999, such as 99.9999900000000000001 ? Can you rephrase your question to clarify these matters?

Comment: I'm curious about what is being measured in metres that would need more than three decimal places. But anyway, in the context of a web form presumably you would set a maximum number of decimal places so why not just say "1 - 99.99999m", saving space by not spelling out "metres"?